# How can I click this button using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
<button name="main" type="submit" class="mainfont">
التسجيل</button>
```

**XPath:**

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[18]/font/button
```

**Full XPath:**

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[18]/font/button
```

How can I click this button in selenium? I have tried different methods but none worked, some notes:

- There are different submit buttons called "main" with mainfont class
- I tried using the XPath but the function also requires me to use the text inside the button, which is in arabic characters that split into two lines in python text editor, which ofcourse does not work as it needs to be in 1 line, but if I erase the space and make it into one code line, it won't work (probably because it is written in two lines in the HTML code?)
  Edit: added code

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    #
    
    path = "XXXX"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
    
    #
    
    driver.get("XXXX")
    driver.maximize_window()
    #
    
    login1 = driver.find_element_by_name("liun")
    login1.send_keys("XXXX")
    time.sleep(2)
    login1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    #
    try:
        element1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.title_is, "XXXX"))
        )
    finally:
        login2 = driver.find_element_by_name("gsw")
        login2.send_keys("XXXX")
        login2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        pass
    # THE CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK
    html = '''
    <button name="main" type="submit" class="mainfont">\nالتسجيل</button>
     '''
    driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='\nالتسجيل']"))).click()
```

Comment: I copied the text you provided `التسجيل` and tried several text editors, in all of them it displayed just fine.

Comment: @Bertik23 https://imgur.com/a/OfhoNOJ here is what i meant

Comment: Ok, try replacing the linebreak with `\n` and having all on one line like this: `print("\nالتسجيل")`

Answer (score 1):

I made the `HTML` that you've provided and could create a `xpath` with text and `clicked` on it using `Explicit waits` :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
html = '''
<button name="main" type="submit" class="mainfont">التسجيل</button>
 '''

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='التسجيل']"))).click()
print('Done successfully clicking')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Did not work
I think the problem is that the text inside the button is saved in two different lines, here is what happens when I copy paste the button text imgur.com/a/OfhoNOJ

Comment: why are you printing the text ? just to give example ? I used pycharm and could execute whatever I have written above.

Comment: You can excute the code properly, but the one lined button text does not match the code on the server (two lined), therefore not getting the button clicked through python code.
I used print as an example of how the code split in two line in selenium functions

Comment: If you pay attention I have this line in my code and xpath as well, `html = '''
<button name="main" type="submit" class="mainfont">التسجيل</button>
 '''` and it works flawlessly at my end.

Comment: I still haven't figured out why it does not work on my end. I have the added the code if you could figure out if there is anything wrong in it.

Comment: You do not need `\n`, show me a screenshot how does it look in your IDE ? also which IDE you are using ?